# Which iPhone 4S Cases actually fit?

Tags: iphone, case

Alot of existing iPhone 4 cases are now being marketed as iPhone 4S cases; but I'm not sure that all of them would be compatible with an iPhone 4S. Can anyone who has found a case that fits add it to the answers?

> For example my girlfriend has two Incipio iPhone 4 cases (DermaShot
>   and NGP) and neither of them fit my new iPhone 4S (due to the position
>   of the mute switch and the volume buttons) despite the Incipio site
>   saying that they are iPhone 4S cases.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, any case made for the iPhone 4 (CDMA) will fit the iPhone 4S. The iPhone 4 (GSM) is now the odd man out.

Comment: @cksum - So pretty much every iPhone 4 case in the UK that has cut out for the mute switch and volume buttons is out?

Comment: Not necessarily. It all depends how exact these cases are cut. For example, Apple simply increase the whole in its bumper to accommodate both models. Most aren't that precise in their design so imagine most would work. It all depends on how perfect a fit you'd like I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Cases that are cut for specifically the iphone 4s or the CDMA version of the iphone 4 should fit the 4s.

Some iphone 4 cases will fit the original (gsm) version of the iphone *and* the CDMA version (the cut away around the mute button is large enough to support it in either position, basically). These should also be fine.

I've got an iphone 4 "bumper" from Apple that's been cut for both versions of the iphone 4, and it fits my 4s just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I actually went to an AT&T store and asked specifically which of the Otterbox's worked with the new iPhone4s. They pointed me to the Defender series even though the print on the packaging said iPhone4 (Not iPhone4s). The case fits/works great. The nice thing about overpaying for the case at the AT&T store was that I have 30 days to return the case, no questions asked. (YMMV)